# password design attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

My component has a property that is a password to a web service.  The current data types for design view are String/Int/Bool and they all display during the design time.  Is there a way to display a password field with a mask?

```
<design:attribute name="password" label="Password" description="account login" />
```

Comment: If the answer below works great. Either way, though, this would be a really good idea on IdeaExchange.

Comment: the answer below is probably on a pre-released Salesforce build.  Hopefully it's coming soon.

Comment: No sorry the answer below about type=password is incorrect (I'm on the app builder team at salesforce and would know if we had implemented that)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry this is currently not possible. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm for list of available tags and attributes in design resources.

Comment: So now you know this is a limitation. Any chance the team may implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an attribute to say the field type is password : type="password"
like below

```
<design:attribute name="password" label="Password" type="password" 
description="account login" />
```

Comment: Just tried it and it looks like it's not an allowed attribute. Error: Failed to save undefined: Type is not a supported design attribute.: Source

Comment: This is not a valid answer. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm for list of available tags and attributes